# Get a column in output while grouping but without grouping that column only in case when only there is only one row for grouped column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

**Table1**

```
t1Id
t1Name
```

**Table2**

```
t2Id
t2Name
```

**Table1_Table2_Mapping**

```
t1Id
t2Id
```

In this below query, as a second column in output, I want the t2Name Column where `Having COUNT(t1Id) = 1` and I want some fixed value ('Common') where `Having COUNT(t1Id) > 1`

```
Select t1Id 
from Table1_Table2_Mapping
Group By t1Id
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT m.t1Id,
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN MAX(t2.t2Name)
         ELSE 'Common'
       END
FROM   Table1_Table2_Mapping m
       JOIN Table2 t2
         ON t2.t2Id = m.t2Id
GROUP  BY m.t1Id
```

Comment: +1000000 Brilliant! Just in 2 mins. Whooaaao SO!! Thanks very very much @Martin :-)